# Facebook API collect pages in certain country

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the facebook api, is it possible to have a query to get facebook pages in a certain country?

I have been searching on google on how to do it or any alternatives but no luck.

I am currently using C# to interact with facebook api.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no endpoint to search for Pages in certain countries. Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Comment: is it possible for city or latitude and longitude?

Comment: It's all in the docs I linked! You can specify a lat/lng with a distance parameter in the place search.